# Merging the values from three tables into one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three string values that I split on a pipe deliminator and I need to merge these values into one table.

I have set up a function already to split these values and place them into three seperate temporary tables.

I need these values in one table. How can I do this.?

```
SET @QuestionData = '5|7|2'
SET @QuestionsDataCorrect = '0|1|0'
SET @QuestionsCount = '1|1|1'

DECLARE @QuestionsPrimaryTable Table (QuestionsId nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @QuestionsPrimaryTable
SELECT Item FROM SplitString(@QuestionData, '|')

DECLARE @QuestionsCorrectTemp Table (CorrectId nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @QuestionsCorrectTemp
SELECT Item FROM SplitString(@QuestionsDataCorrect, '|')

DECLARE @QuestionsCountTemp Table (CountId nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @QuestionsCountTemp
SELECT Item FROM SplitString(@QuestionsCount, '|')

select * from @QuestionsPrimaryTable
select * from @QuestionsCorrectTemp
select * from @QuestionsCountTemp
```

My end goal would be to have the values like this

```
5 0 1
7 1 1
2 0 1
```

Comment: I'm curious, why did you accept an answer that can produce incorrect results?

Comment: It works for me. I have tested it a few times with different sets of results and every time the end is as expected.

Comment: It is up to you of course, but for those who find this question later - this is `undefined behavior`. The order in which `IDENTITY` numbers are generated while multiple rows are inserted into a table is not guaranteed, unless there is an `ORDER BY` clause. It is easy to confirm it using the following.

Comment: Write a `SELECT` that is complex enough to use a parallel plan. `INSERT` results of this `SELECT` into a temp table with `IDENTITY` column. Run the same `INSERT ... SELECT` into another temp table, but with `OPTION(MAXDOP 1)` second time. Do not use `ORDER BY`. Compare contents of temp tables and check the order of rows. This behavior is not limited to parallel plans, it is just an easy way to demonstrate the problem. Whenever the query plans changes the order of rows in the result can change (without `ORDER BY`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an identity column to your temporary tables and then create a new table using a join on this column.

Start by adding an identity column:

```
DECLARE @QuestionsPrimaryTable Table (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), QuestionsId nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @QuestionsPrimaryTable
SELECT Item FROM SplitString(@QuestionData, '|')

DECLARE @QuestionsCorrectTemp Table (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), CorrectId nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @QuestionsCorrectTemp
SELECT Item FROM SplitString(@QuestionsDataCorrect, '|')

DECLARE @QuestionsCountTemp Table (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), CountId nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @QuestionsCountTemp
SELECT Item FROM SplitString(@QuestionsCount, '|')
```

THen declare a new table and insert all values from other three tables using joining then by ID:

```
DECLARE @QuestionsAll Table (QuestionsId nvarchar(max), CorrectId nvarchar(max), CountId nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @QuestionsAll (QuestionsId, CorrectId, CountId)
SELECT prim.QuestionsId, corr.CorrectId, cnt.CountId 
FROM   @QuestionsPrimaryTable prim
    INNER JOIN @QuestionsCorrectTemp corr ON prim.Id = corr.Id
    INNER JOIN @QuestionsCountTemp cnt ON prim.Id = count.Id
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the order in which split elements are inserted into temp tables will be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the item number in the result set, so you can then join your data using it. So, your function needs to return the item position too, and then you can do something something like this:

```
SET @QuestionData = '5|7|2'
SET @QuestionsDataCorrect = '0|1|0'
SET @QuestionsCount = '1|1|1'

DECLARE @QuestionsPrimaryTable Table (QuestionsId nvarchar(max), pos int)
INSERT INTO @QuestionsPrimaryTable
SELECT Item, ItemPos FROM SplitString(@QuestionData, '|')

DECLARE @QuestionsCorrectTemp Table (CorrectId nvarchar(max), pos int)
INSERT INTO @QuestionsCorrectTemp
SELECT Item, ItemPos FROM SplitString(@QuestionsDataCorrect, '|')

DECLARE @QuestionsCountTemp Table (CountId nvarchar(max), pos int)
INSERT INTO @QuestionsCountTemp
SELECT Item, ItemPos FROM SplitString(@QuestionsCount, '|')

select * from 
  @QuestionsPrimaryTable P 
  join @QuestionsCorrectTemp C on P.pos = C.pos
  join @QuestionsCountTemp CO on P.pos = CO.pos
```

This assumes all those 3 lists have always equal number of items.

Comment: Since we have to change the `SplitString` function any way, there is one more option. Make it accept three delimited strings and let it produce the table with three columns at once as it parses the source strings. This option removes an extra step of joining the results, but it is not flexible - the number of columns is fixed.

Comment: And you don't really need the table variables either, you could just join the result of the function, although without testing I'm not sure if that causes extra operations or not.